# Is dynamoDb a good fit to maintain notification data that can scale in future?

Tags: database, mongodb, architecture, amazon-dynamodb

In our application we currently use dynamoDb to store the notification details. So a scheduler runs twice a day which queries "notificationType"(pk -> notifiactionType, sk -> userId).
In each item there is an attribute(timestamp), based on which if the timestamp is more than the current time will send a trigger(more business logic that for some records one day after the timestamp a mail needs to be sent). Now once the user performs the activity for which the notification is sent, then will delete the entry

My query is that, if the data grows large for a notificationType, then retrieval of all the data is redundant because for some records the notification is not going to be sent. Hence more read capacity is used and that might potentially increase the cost in later point of time.
In this case would it be wise to use the existing dynamoDb or move to any other db like mongoDb, cassandra or any other db.

Note: My primary concern is the cost

Comment: Do you require the scheduler to run twice per day or would it work for your use case as well if notifications would be send immediately when their timestamp passes?

Comment: Is my assumption correct that you also use that DynamoDB table to store all notifications (no matter if they have a past or future timestamp) permanently?

Comment: @Dunedan, for your question 1. It depends on the notificationType. For some notificationType, we would send the mail immediately the timestamp passes. For other notificationType, let's say we need to give 2nd day reminder, 4th day reminder once it passes the timestamp. (i.e 2 days past the timestamp)
2)For now, there is no requirement to store the data permanently and so we delete the notification once the user performs the action for which the notification is sent
Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered expiring old ones with a TTL so you don’t have to scale up?

Comment: @hephalump, the data stays till the user performs the required action, for which the notification is sent for. So once the timestamp passes, a first mail will be triggered. And even after 2 days past the timestamp, the user didn't complete the required action, a mail has to be triggered on the 2nd day. So data deletion is done only after the user's task completion

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a workflow engine that can model the notification process per user instead of a batch job. This way you can avoid scanning large amounts of data as the engine would rely on durable timers to execute actions at the appropriate time.

My open-source project [temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/) which I led at Uber is used by multiple companies for notification like scenarios and was tested up 200 million open parallel workflows.